# How do I find out where my root URL is being served from in Apache?

Tags: apache, centos

I've recently got a VPS server and it came installed with CentOS, WHM and cPanel. I'm trying to find where the physical folder location the root URL of the server IP is being served. When I go to the root IP in a browser, I get a redirect to "/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi" with "SORRY!" and some error resolve details.

The server has a web-site running under "/cPanel" and also WHM runs on ":2083".

I'm trying take control of the content served directly at the /, and replace that defaultwebpage.cgi with an index.html.

I've tried httpd -V to check where the httpd.conf, is and then spotted a `<VirtualHost *>` in that config file, which points to a DocumentRoot of /use/local/apache/htdocs . But if I place index.html in this folder and try to hit it via /index.html, I still get routed to that defaultwebpage.cgi. Can anyone help me understand why its rerouting and not picking up that index.html?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file in the htdocs directory?

Comment: check the httpd-vhost file as well .. to see if there are other virtual host configurations.

Comment: There isn't a .htaccess in the htdocs directory. There isn't a httpd-vhost file either.

Comment: Try `find -name defaultwebpage.cgi`.  Find where that file is and look at what it has.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try /var/www/html, at least that's in Ubuntu

If it's not it, then try going to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and find the DocumentRoot option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is CentOS and there is a /var/www/html, tried adding the index.html to there but still doesn't serve (that dir was empty). The document root is as I said in my post and points to /usr/local/apache/htdocs.